# Values setValueAt()

Tags: java, swing, object, jtable, int

I'm trying to create a table , and i'm using the setValueAt() to add the values to my table.

Some of my code :

```
  int nalt=1+((altmax-altmin)/incr);
    tabela=new JTable(new String[nalt][6],colunas);

    for(int i=0;i<=(nalt-1);i=i){
        for(int j=altmin;j<=altmax;j=j+incr){
            tabela.setValueAt(""+j, i, 0);

        i=i+1;
        }
```

The thing is , if i leave the value = (""+j) it works fine, but if i leave only (j) i get alot of errors.

i tried to do this:

```
   int nalt=1+((altmax-altmin)/incr);
    tabela=new JTable(new String[nalt][6],colunas);

    for(int i=0;i<=(nalt-1);i=i){
        for(int j=altmin;j<=altmax;j=j+incr){
            Object ty=new Integer(j);
            tabela.setValueAt(ty, i, 0);

        i=i+1;
        }
```

and this :

```
        int nalt=1+((altmax-altmin)/incr);
    tabela=new JTable(new String[nalt][6],colunas);

    for(int i=0;i<=(nalt-1);i=i){
        for(int j=altmin;j<=altmax;j=j+incr){
            tabela.setValueAt(new Integer(j), i, 0);

        i=i+1;
        }
```

but still i got alot of errors .
i could do the first way , leaving (""+j) , but i will need that value , and i'm getting trouble converting that object to int . 
If you could help me trying to understand why i'm getting errors that would be nice. Or help me converting that object to a int . I mean i will need to use the .getValueAt(...) and i think i'm getting troubles to converting because the obect is (""+number) , or maybe im wrong .

Thanks

Comment: you should ppost what errors are you having  `setValueAt(Object, int , int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you setup your JTable with a String array: `new JTable(new String[nalt][6],colunas);` but then you try to add an integer:  `tabela.setValueAt(new Integer(j), i, 0);`. The solution is to set up your table with an integer array in the first place:

```
tabela=new JTable(new Integer[nalt][6],colunas);
```

Comment: Good advice, 1+ up-vote. Also 1+ up-vote to @user2627865 for accepting this answer.